# return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: rss_news_post.name_category

Tags: django, sqlite3

**гуглил, менял поле на не уникальное, удалил эту колонку(name_category),  и всё равно возвращает ошибку**

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
import datetime





class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
     related_name='children',
      db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
      order_insertion_by = ['name_category']



class Category(models.Model):
  class Meta():
    db_table = 'category_article'
    ordering = ['name']
    verbose_name = 'Категория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

  name = models.CharField(max_length=150, 
    unique=True, 
    verbose_name='Категория')
  slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Транслит', null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name



class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    text = models.TextField()
    text_an = models.TextField('Краткое описание новости', max_length=150)
    category_content = models.CharField('Название категори новости',max_length=10)
    date = models.DateField(default=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    add_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,
     upload_to='images/blog/%Y/%m/%d',
      help_text='300x250px',
       verbose_name='url img')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "_" + str(self.title)
```

**вот вывод более подробнее**

```
        Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, rss_news, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying rss_news.0016_auto_20171211_1406...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: rss_news_post.name_category

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 238, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 206, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/kiril/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: rss_news_post.name_category
```

Comment: И что за ошибка?

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: python manage.py migrate

Comment: нене, тож самое,

Comment: 1) Удалите указанную таблицу. 2) Удалите таблицу django_migrations в базе. 3) Проведите снова миграцию.

Comment: крч пришлось много что удалить), придется юзерку для админа, и демо посты заново пилить))

Comment: можно было их сохранить через dump